# Upload photo to an album AND to wall in facebook through php. So we get a big picture on wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photo

I manage to sent a photo from my server to a users album on facebook.
But this photo is not automaticly seen on his wall. And specifically it is not seen as a big photo, like how photos from albums are shown on a wall.

So I suppose I have to do a second request to tell facebook to put the photo on the wall.

I have these 2 requests:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST',
  array(
    'source' => '@/var/www/cover/test.jpg',
    'message' => $_POST['msg']
  )
);
```

This returns for example:
[id] => 358313274248558 [post_id] => 100001736648729_358281023575116

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
  array(
    'message' => $_POST['msg'],
    'object_attachment' => $ret_obj['id']
  )
);
```

I have tried for the 'object_attachment' 358313274238558, 100001796648729_358281027575116 and 358281027575116. But facebook tells me that those are not correct.

So how on earth can we add a photo to a wall, which we just put in an album, and which we want to show in a large format (not as a little thumbnail).

If there is another way, without using albums, that is fine with me.

Please help. I know there have been a few questions already about photo uploads to facebook here on stackoverflow, I think I have read them all about 10 times already. It seems there is no answer yet. Somebody said we could post to /me/links but facebook doesn't seem to be able to handle links like http(s)://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=358309510905631 anymore.

I have changed the ids in this post so they are not linked to actual stuff, they are here as examples.

Thanks

---

edit:

> Ok, it seems a post of an image to an album is also a post of a big image to the wall **IF the user allows the app to do public stuff**. Because I was developing, I told the app to not do public stuff and only show stuff to me personally.
>
> So there is no need to do 2 requests, just adding a photo to the album is enough to have it appear big on the users wall IF the user allows app activity to be public.
>
> It is still somewhat confusing that a second request seems unable to also add the foto in a large size to the wall.

Comment: You should at least include often used tags, such as the PHP tag. Furthermore, if you have answers you should create an answer, not edit your question.